# How to find nested elements in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var button = (Button) sender;

   var stackPanel = button.Parent as StackPanel;
   var childStackPanel = stackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is StackPanel).FirstOrDefault();

   // var textbox = childStackPanel.Children.Where(a => a is StackPanel).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Not able to get Element within Element, textbox in this case.

But it gives an error when I code `chidStackPanel.Children`. No Children Property available.

Comment: UIElement has no Children property. Maybe you should give some details about what you want to do, because I'm sure there should be a better way than using Children properties...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Where` is filtering out Children, which is a collection of `UIElement`, which does not have a `Children` property. You need to cast it to a `StackPanel` too. But rather than that, `OfType` to the rescue:

```
var childStackPanel = stackPanel.Children.OfType<StackPanel>().FirstOrDefault();
```

[`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) filters out items that are not of that type, while also casting them to that type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "var" syntax derives the type at compile-time from the right-hand side of the statement.

Even though you've explicitly selected the first child that is a StackPanel using "Where" the derived type at compile-time will still be UIElement. UIElement doesn't have the Children property.

You'll need to explicitly cast the result of that statement to a StackPanel using "(StackPanel)" or "as".